# Get curly brackets in Windows VM

Tags: windows, mac, virtual-machine, visual-studio

I'm on a Mac and I use a Windows VM for c# programming. I'm not able to type curly brackets in Visual Studio or anywhere else in the VM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do Shift+Alt+8 and Shift+Alt+9 work? I believe those are the shortcuts on Mac. Alternatively, do Alt+123 and Alt+125 work?

Comment: Those don't do anything

Comment: It's `Alt+0123` and `Alt+0125` (ciphers typed on the numpad) @ShiffleMcDoobles

Comment: Apparently only the right option/alt and 0/9 gives me the brackets. Strange...

Comment: Shifted [ & ] should be { & } - same on Mac & Win, even over RDC or a VM. If they're not, then we need more details on both OSes - which VM, keyboard layout & assigned language

Comment: What about running the On Screen Keyboard (`osk.exe`)? Though that's gonna be a pain if you type them much, as I suspect you do.

Answer (score 1):

`[`: right <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
`]`: right <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>
`{`: right <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>
`}`: right <kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>

Software: MacOS 10.14.5, Virtual Box 5.2.30, Windows 10 Pro

Hardware: Swedish Keyboard Layout, MacBook Pro